# macOS – In an Electron app, can you combine `Command` with `MediaNextTrack` as a global shortcut?

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to add a `Cmd+MediaNextTrack` shortcut to this app I'm building.

Combined shortcuts (like e.g. `Cmd+Shift+Space`) seem to work fine in my Electron app.

I am aware of the Security & Privacy / Accessibility setting that needs to be enabled for `MediaNextTrack` to be accessible. It's enabled locally; the following code works:

```
    let successfullyRegistered = globalShortcut.register('MediaNextTrack', async () => {
        console.log("==> activated.")
    });
```

and it actually takes over any "next track" action from Spotify and correctly logs to console.

Also the `successfullyRegistered` boolean returns as `true`.

**However if I change that code to:**

```
    let successfullyRegistered = globalShortcut.register('Cmd+MediaNextTrack', async () => {
        console.log("==> activated.")
    });
```

The console is no longer activated.

But `successfullyRegistered` is `true`.

And `globalShortcut.isRegistered("Cmd+MediaNextTrack")` returns `true` as well.

Various variations of Cmd don't work either: `Command+MediaNextTrack`, `CommandOrControl+MediaNextTrack` don't work either.

---

**Question**

Is there another way to activate that command + next track shortcut in the app?

Answer (score 0):

After testing, `CommandOrControl+MediaNextTrack` works on Linux and Windows.